# How to change Intellij CamelHumps behavior as it was in 2017.1?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij 2017.1 (and I'm quite sure in older ones) there is an option editor->general->smart keys-> Use "CamelHumps" Word

This option used to work like in Eclipse: Pressing control + arrow left/right makes words navigation to jump to the next uppercase letter, but when we double click over the word it used to select the whole text block.

Now in 2017.2-5 Intellij it is forcing the CamelHumps behavior to mouse double clicks when you select it. Is there a way to make the behavior only for the keyboard navigation and not the mouse one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a setting for that:

[image: honor]

**Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click**.

You need to disable it.

Comment: Hey, tyvm. I've seen this option somewhere, but always when looking for it in intellij I was using 'Camel' in my search, an that always led to the "Smart key" options that are inside of the Editor->general->smart key, making me believe there was only 1 option related to CamelHumps.